# Selenium hangs at driver.get() only for one website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've been facing this issue for quite some time now and since I'm a novice in webscraping I cannot seem to find an answer.

I want to scrape some websites I pass from a list. My Chrome driver works all of them but one: https://www.studentbeans.com/student-discount/it/cats. The driver gets stuck already at the driver.get() request for a very long time (sometimes more than an hour) and I always need to interrput it.

The code worked fine a couple of months ago, and all of a sudden not anymore for this specific link.
After doing my research on the web I have added and combined all possible options to the driver, but nothing seems to work.

Chrome Driver version : 107.0.5304.62 (updated)
Chrome Version :  107.0.5304.107 (updated)
Selenium Version : 4.2.0

Can someone please explain to me the reason why the driver gets stuck? How can I solve this? Thank you a lot.

Driver connector:
`

```
class SeleniumConnector() : 

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

    def connector(self, link: str): 
        """Creates a driver instance for google Chrome and allows to connect to given link"""
        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-notifications") #disabling notifications
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking") #to avoid chat popus
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') if os.name == 'nt' else None
        self.options.add_argument("--incognito")
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        self.options.add_argument("--headless")  #to avoid popups of every window
        desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
        desired_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True 
        self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        self.options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= self.options)
        driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
  
        try: 
            print('Connecting to..... {}'.format(link))
            driver.delete_all_cookies()
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(15) 
            driver.get(link)
           
        except: 
            print(f'Wrong link: {link}')
        return driver
```

`

Backtrace after keyboard interrupt:
`

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
2022-11-12 13:48:17,414 INFO ====== WebDriver manager ======
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\fetza\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 281, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\---\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Please share the URL of the site which causes problems. Otherwise nobody will be able to help.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? The above code is working perfectly fine in headless mode and also in normal mode.

Comment: I tried to run the code several times, but with this link the driver gets stuck at driver.get() for hours without returning anything. I am expecting to be able  to gon on with the next part of the code, but I don't even get there.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works well. Here's the code I've executed:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.studentbeans.com/student-discount/it/cats')
```

Here's the result I've got:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. I tried to run it from my work laptop and it works. Then I tried from mine, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are both computers in the same network?

Comment: Yes, they are both on the same network.